# the window size is bigger than the specific size when create a window with a fix size

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *

master = Tk()
master.resizable(False, False)
master.geometry("100x100")

master.mainloop()
```

When using the simple code above to create a fix size window, the actual window client area's size is about 126x126 pixels. How to create a window with exact size in tkinter in python?

Comment: `master.geometry("74x74")`?

Comment: What platform are you on? Some platforms may have a minimum size in order to fit the buttons in the window header.

Comment: The platform is windows 10 64bit Home version, Python 3.7.4, Tkinter version 8.6

Comment: if master.geometry("74x74"), the actual size will be around 94x94.